# How to remove failed download of a Docker image

Tags: docker

I tried to download a docker image, but after downloading some layers I ran out of space:

```
8bcebcb03767: Download complete 
650ad29672ea: Download complete 
b9984e72f0c9: Download complete 
...
cf891de99fe6: Download complete 
71703d4c29e6: Download complete 
4349060a9f4b: Downloading  1.466GB/1.466GB
f66e40e861c9: Downloading  910.7MB/935.5MB
f9be839f447e: Downloading  477.8MB/477.8MB
7e32910bef0b: Waiting 
fa1a325a3278: Waiting 
ed21ba5b2303: Waiting 
68c302f66d48: Waiting 
988432025db2: Waiting 
41f3021e6eb1: Waiting 
b1ffaaf942d0: Waiting 
07f683e4c14b: Waiting 
8d636fd01855: Waiting 
8ac01bd91ea5: Waiting 
17f8202c6481: Waiting 
docker: write /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob578490561: no space left on device.
See 'docker run --help'
```

I think that all the layers with "Download complete" status are still in the disk, how can I *clean* the failed installation, and get rid of those?

Comment: Try to remove this temp file `rm /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob578490561`

Comment: The whole /var/lib/docker/tmp/ was empty.  No other locations to look at?

Answer (score 1):

I dont get your question at all but I think you are looking for this
`docker image prune`

This will remove images that you dont use.

Comment: I think `docker image prune` will remove images that have no container associated. The problem is that since my `docker pull` command failed before finishing, I don't see the image in the list, and indeed prune did not free any byte.

Comment: Do you see something with this command? ` docker images -q -f dangling=true `

Comment: You need to use `docker image prune --all` otherwise it's only going to remove "dangling" images (previous versions of existing images).